SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint even though I save it in the right order
I am adding first the primary table Order, then the Order item to the database. The Order item is supposed to have the OrderID saved after the Order was saved to the database. The Order is successfully saved to the database, but the Order item for some reason can't see it straight away and throws an error

SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint

I tried async and sync but both didn't work. Any idea what I could do?
// Save Order
Narudzba narudzba = new Narudzba
{
    datum_vrijeme = selectedDateTime.Value,
    racun = GenerateRacun(),
    status = "Zaprimljeno",
    Korisnik_id_korisnik = korisnik.id_korisnik
};

await _narudzbaServices.AddNarudzbuAsync(narudzba);

// Save Order items

foreach (var jelo in _selectedFoodItems)
{
    Stavka_narudzbe stavka_Narudzbe = new Stavka_narudzbe
    {
        kolicina = "1",
        prilagodbe = null,
        Narudzba_id_narudzba = narudzba.id_narudzba,
        Jelo_id_jelo = jelo.id_jelo,
        Pice_id_pice = null
    };
    _stavka_narudzbeServices.AddStavkeNarudzbe(stavka_Narudzbe);
}

The way that services repository adds the Order to the database:
public override Task<int> AddAsync(Narudzba entity, bool saveChanges = true)
{
    var narudzba = new Narudzba
    {
        datum_vrijeme = entity.datum_vrijeme,
        racun = entity.racun,
        status = entity.status,
        Korisnik_id_korisnik = entity.Korisnik_id_korisnik
    };

    Entities.Add(narudzba);

    if (saveChanges)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(SaveChanges());
    }
    else
    {
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}


What is _narudzbaServices (and others)? What AddNarudzbuAsync (and others) do?

Services communicate with the Repository->database. They just add the Order to the database.

The question is how they work internally. The description does not provide any understanding needed to help you with the problem. Can you please provide a [mre].

@GGs the phrase communicate with the Repository->database. explains nothing. We can't guess what code the Repository class uses. The question's code contains several weird constructs already, like using Task.FromResult in an async method. That means the method is not asynchronous even though it claims otherwise.

@GGs are you using EF Core? In that case the problem is caused by the non-repository CRUD class that's used. EF doesn't need a save order. A DbContext is a Unit-of-Work that detects all changes in the objects it tracks, and saves all of them in the correct order when a single call to SaveChanges is made. If you call SaveChanges for every object, you completely break EF Core's functionality

I figured it out. The issue was that since the ID was automatically generated in Azure I couldn't retrieve that order by ID from the database, I can retrieve the order by anything else though. Or another option is to return the created Narudzba after Adding it to the database aswell.

The issue you're encountering typically happens when the foreign key reference in the "Order item" table doesn't correctly point to an existing "Order" ID. This can occur if the "Order" isn't actually committed to the database before you try to insert the "Order item".

Ensure that the ID of the "Order" is available immediately after saving it to the database.
Properly handle async operations to wait for the "Order" to be saved before proceeding with the "Order item".

